# is there any way to delete the previously added records in a particular session in flask?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Here while executing the below code, record1 was saved into db and there is an issue with record2 as we are expecting role_id a integer but got a string, so is there any way that i could remove the record1 from db as the endpoint is not executed successfully

```
class First(Resource):
    def get(self):
        try:
            record1 = UserModel(username='xxx',password='yyyy')
            record1.save_to_db()
            record2 = RoleModel(role_id='aaa')
            record2.save_to_db()
        except:
            db.session.rollback()
        finally:
            db.session.close()
```

Comment: A rollback should apply to the collected operations since the beginning of the current transaction. Only calling commit or flush ends the respective transaction. If something goes wrong here, the entire transaction is withdrawn by calling up rollback. Look [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_basics.html) and [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_transaction.html#managing-transactions). So you can change the ```save_to_db()``` function so that the object is added to the session but a commit is omitted depending on a passed boolean argument.

Comment: Thanks for the information it worked out for me i have modified the code in save_to_db() and it worked for me.